# Can Google Sheets use date data validation to require one column's data to be more recent than another's

Tags: google-sheets

I would like my target completion column to have a date that is greater than in my start column.  Excel supports a date validation option but I do not see this in Google Sheets.

Is it there and I just don't know how to use it or is my only option to write an Apps Script add-on?

Comment: Please don't post the same question across sites on [se].

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with a specific date but I think would require a script if to apply on a row by row basis (a moving target for the comparisons).

An alternative is to apply Conditional formatting... instead (to warn of but not prevent inappropriate entries).